# Issue on ngOptions track by

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have some issue with AngularJs option/selector which I uses `ngOptions` to create. The problem I have is that it doesn't trigger the method I have in `ngChange`. I found out that's because in `actionList` the `name` property isn't unique. So if I change so they are unique it will works as intended. However I want them to be named like how it is now.

So I guess I could try something like `ng-options="action.name for action in ctrl.actionList track by action.value"`. But it doesn't work. Anyone who can help me out here?

**HTML**

```
<select id="someOptions" class="dropdown dropdown-md"
    ng-model="ctrl.settingAction"
    ng-change="ctrl.onChangeAction()"
    ng-options="action.name for action in ctrl.actionList">
</select>
```

**Data structure**

```
actionList = [{
    name: "Running Man"
    value: "RUN"
}, {
    name: "Running Man"
    value: "JUMP"
}]
```

**JS**

```
public onChangeAction(): void {
    console.log(this.settingAction);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 var ctrl = this;
 this.actionList =[{
    "name": "Running Man",
    "value": "RUN"
}, {
    "name": "Running Man",
    "value": "JUMP"
}];

this.onChangeAction = function(){
 alert(this.settingAction.value);
}
 
          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
 <select id="someOptions" class="dropdown dropdown-md"
    ng-model="ctrl.settingAction"
    ng-change="ctrl.onChangeAction()"
    ng-options="action.name for action in ctrl.actionList">
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Mark if it has helped

Comment: It does work, however in my production code it is same but it doesn't work. So I'm not quite ready yet to mark it resolved :/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using 'controller as' syntax. Can you confirm that the `onChangeAction()` function is being set in the vm/self like this?

```
var vm = this;
vm.onChangeAction = function (): void {
    console.log(this.settingAction);
}
```

Comment: that's correct I have just cut down the parts so it I just highlight the part I have issue with